# Geometry Nodes - Peeling surface along curve with arbitrary rotation

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I am continuing to work on a geometry nodes set up that peels paper up given proximity to the interior of a given target object. Thanks to the great curve rolling tutorial from Cartesian Caramel I have made progress.

[image]

Given that in reality is unrealistic for the peeling to happen entirely in parallel I want to randomly rotate the each curve so that each section peeling up at a slight different angle from the others. As it is rotating the peel direction of the curve rotates the entire generated geometry, which is isn't what I want.

Here is the desired effect achieved through an ordinary curve modifier on a single subdivided plane.
[image]

However as it is the curve to mesh is creating the final geometry the peeling sections are always created according the normal of the peeling curves. Maybe this is a limitation of doing it in this way: probably the peel geometry should be modified by the curves it is paired with via instance indices rather than created directly from it.

It seems to me that each point in the peeled mesh geometry must be constrained to move *only* in the z axis and the tangent  of the curve, as this is how it works when you actually peel up paper at an angle. But I'm not sure how to implement this.

[image]